# Mapbox: Show tooltips by default, without having to click a marker

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary, markers, mapbox

What is the best way to have all tooltips on a Mapbox map be open on page load, without having to click on a marker to show it? I tried removing the `opacity: 0` on `.leaflet-popup` but that didn't work because it appears that they are built in the DOM on the fly by JS.

Can this even be done? I realize it's not conventional, but I have a mock I'm trying to recreate that essentially has the markers looking like tooltips, with the title inside. I've searched and searched for ways to customize markers, but the only thing I can find is to use your own custom image. Since I have to have dynamic titles showing that won't work, so my plan now is to use 1x1 transparent pngs for the marker images and just show the tooltips by default.

**Edit**

Here's my code:

```
// Setup map
var map = L.mapbox.map("destinations-map", "xxx")
    .setView([40, -74.50], 2);

// Load regions from JSON file
var loadRegions = function () {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/regions",
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data.regions, function(i, region) {
                L.mapbox.markerLayer({
                    type: "Feature",
                    geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: region.coordinates
                    },
                    properties: {
                        title: region.title
                    }
                })
                .addTo(map)
                .openPopup();
            });

        }
    });
};

// Initially load region markers
loadRegions();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify the default behavior of popups by extending the Map object in Leaflet. Leaflet.js makes extensive use of a pseudo-classical inheritance pattern, so you have a lot of work already cut out for you. Try:

```
L.Map = L.Map.extend({
    openPopup: function(popup) {
        this._popup = popup;

        return this.addLayer(popup).fire('popupopen', {
            popup: this._popup
        });
    }
});
```

And then when you add your popups, open them directly like so:

```
L.marker([65.10, 14.77])
  .addTo(map)
  .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am popup 1.")
  .openPopup();
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/P543v/

Comment: Great, thanks! That works for opening the last popup by default, but not all of them. In fact, the first chunk (`L.Map.extend`) isn't doing anything it appears. I'm not exactly sure what the intent of that is though. Is that to be able to open more than one popup at a time?

Comment: Did you add the extension at the top of your script? That snippet overrides the default openPopup method which also contains `this.closePopup();`. By overriding it without the closePopup part, the map should not close other popups when new ones are clicked.

Comment: I added an example to my answer. That should hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I think my issue is how I'm creating markers. I'm looping through JSON data inside `L.mapbox.markerLayer ()...})` and then calling `.addTo(map)` to that. A little bit different than the way you are doing it. I updated my question with my actual code.

Comment: I see. It's not clear where you configure your popups. But the main issue here is the `L.Map.extend` part. Are the popups being opened on clicks, and closed when you click another popup? In that case, the overriding part is not being registered for some reason.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not configuring popups anywhere. I assume it's just part of the default Mapbox that when you declare a ```title``` it uses that for the popup.

Comment: You might want to skip the markerlayer class and create points instead. That way, you can use some variation of my answer above. "[R]ight now Leaflet/MapBox.js are not designed to show more than one popup at once". http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/mapboxjs/2543-multiple-popups-open-at-the-same-time

Comment: Yep, I just saw that thread too. I will look into using points. Thanks!